# Autogenerated menu based on headings (h1, h2..)?

Tags: wordpress

I use Wordpress as tool for publicizing big chunks of static text (as pages ...) and I would like to have Table of Content, auto-generated based on HTML headings h1,h2,h3...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know any plugins that does the job, maybe there are. But a plugin that would does that would need to parse the current post (using database/on page request), get only the headings(using parser like regex) and use them as a menu (write the results as a html list of ul li). Another addition would be to cache the result according to the page revision but it's your choice.